# Microsoft Graph OData query parameter $expand doesn't seem to work

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I'm currently developing an application that uses an Azure AD instance. I'm trying to query this AD to sync the users to my system. I want to retrieve all the users and their groups. The Microsoft Graph API has the following function for this operation:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf`

However, this gives me the same response as calling: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. Users in my AD do have groups and I did try calling the api with `$select` instead of `$expand`, but also without result.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You say "gives me the same response", can you share the response you receive?  Is the response an error message?

Comment: The response is the list of users. With the `$expand=memberOf` I expect to have a list of groups for that user, but I'm not seeing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding navigation properties on user entities is currently not working on the production (v1.0).  Please see this post for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022980.

Comment: Right, thanks! I tried getting the groups and $expand their members, and I only want to $select the ID's of those users, but that doesn't seem to work as well. Any info on that? `v1.0/groups?$expand=members($select=id)`

Comment: I was trying the same thing, it looks like $expand in combination with $select does not work.. at least for me. When I use the $select the $expand stops working

Comment: On beta it is not working right either. If you try to expand a single navigation property, it expands everything both for the entity itself, and all child entities